# How do I enable userpics in Movable Type

Tags: movabletype

On the user management admin page I can assign userpics to users, but I can't work out how to enable users to set them themselves.
The following code is in the Profile Edit Form template of my System Overview, but the userpic field doesn't appear on the form itself (all the other fields seem to be fine).

```
<mt:SetVarBlock name="field-content">
    <mt:If name="userpic">
    <div id="userpic-preview">
        <$mt:Var name="userpic"$>
    </div>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <mt:else>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    </mt:If>
</mt:SetVarBlock>

<$mt:Include module="Form Field" id="file" class="" label="Userpic"$>
```

I'm a complete novice when it comes to Movable Type, having muddled my way through customising the default theme to get a layout I'm satisfied with, so it's quite possible that I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: are the users using the CMS interface, or some other app?
For example, the community app/pack enable users to upload pictures from the website side.

Comment: @ShmuelFomberg: It's pretty much the default as installed. I've modified the style sheet and templates but haven't added any packages. It seems to me that the facility for userpics is *there* but isn't enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Profile Edit Form is part of the community pack. it will only be used if you are creating a blog with community blog theme.

Comment: Does this imply that it's not possible to customise the Profile Edit Form in the free version of Movable Type?

Comment: It uses functionality that comes with Community Pack, so you can't use it without it.